# How to get nearby Blood Banks in Android Maps via Google API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

How do I get nearby Blood Banks in android? currently I am using this approach in Kotlin via Google API to get the location of nearby Blood Banks,

```
private fun getUrl(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, nearbyPlace: String): String {
    val googlePlaceUrl = StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("location=$latitude,$longitude")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius=$PROXIMITY_RADIUS")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&type=bloodbank")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&sensor=true")
    googlePlaceUrl.append("&key=" + "MYKEY")
    Log.d("MapsActivity", "url = $googlePlaceUrl")
    return googlePlaceUrl.toString()
}
```

I am using keyword bloodbank to get location via Google API but its not showing Blood Banks but some helth centres or hospitals, But If I use this Keyword directly in Google Maps Android App or Website, it accuratly shows me what I want. How do I Improve this query?

Answer (score -1):

You can only use standard type provided by Google. Please refer this link: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

also please try this

> Try to pass "keyword" parameter in place of "type".

```
private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {
    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&keyword=bloodbank");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "API");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=YOUR_LOATION&radius=1000&keyword=bloodbank&sensor=true&key=YOUR_KEY